# Javascript function not getting called from razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I know I've done this before but can't figure out how. Given the following, I want to output the date. The problem I get is getDate('@Model.Date') is written.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDate(date) {
        var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();       
        var dt = new Date(date);
        dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + (offset / -60));        
        return dt;
    }
</script>

<div class="time">
    <font class="time time-type">@Model.DateType:</font> <font class="time">getDate('@Model.Date');</font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the javascript function like this.You need to add a label control and assign the label text from your javascript section.

```
<div class="time">
    <font class="time time-type">@Model.DateType:</font><label id="dateDisplay" class="time"></label>
</div>
```

And you Javascript function assign the text to it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getDate(date) {
        var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();       
        var dt = new Date(date);
        dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + (offset / -60));        
        return dt;
    }

$("#dateDisplay").text(getDate('@Model.Date'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs) with the [Time HtmlElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time)

(if you really have to do it with raw javascript it's easy to convert, this was done in typescript so you can replace `let` with `var` for pure javascript as well)

/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/datetime.cshtml:

```
@model DateTime

<time datetime="@Model.ToString("o")"></time>
```

some Javascript in the root page template/script file:

```
let $timeCache = $('time[datetime]');
// enable to update the display of the date/time if you're using
// momentjs friendly date times
// setInterval(() => updateTime(), 60000);

function updateTime() {
   $timeCache.each((index, element) => {
      let $element = $(element);
      let momentTime = moment($element.attr('datetime'));
      $element.text(momentTime.fromNow());
   });
}
updateTime();
```

Usage:

model

```
public class MyModel
{
  public DateTime StartedOn { get; set; }
}
```

view

```
@model MyModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StartedOn)
```